# I want to assign a new value to cells that are between certain numbers in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to change any numbers between 200 and 300 to 'Asian' for a Demographics report, but I am not sure how to do that in Python. In SQL I would build a case statement like so,
Case
When Ethnicity Between '200' and '300' then 'Asian'. But I am not sure what the equivalent of that would be in Python. I was assigning new values with df.loc like so,

```
df.loc[df['Race 1']== 700, 'Race 1']= 'White'
```

But I can only do it with one value. I am not sure how I would do it when the value is between two numbers. This was my attempt at it:

```
df.loc[(df['Race 1']>= 200) | (df['Race 1']<= 300), 'Race 1']= 'Asian'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I mentioned what I tried in the previous paragraph, but when I tried to run that code I would get an error message :

```
'>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
df.loc[df['Race 1'].between(200, 300, inclusive='left'), 'Race 1'] = 'Asian'
```

**The issue is that, after one assignment, the dtype will become object, preventing further numeric comparisons.**

You might want to use [`cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) defining ranges for each target group.

Another option would be to assign to a temporary column, then overwriting when all substitutions are made.

```
df.loc[df['Race 1'] == 700, 'temp']= 'White'
df.loc[df['Race 1'].between(200, 300, inclusive='left'), 'temp'] = 'Asian'

df['Race 1'] = df.pop('temp')
```

Or use `numpy.select`:

```
import numpy as np

df['Race 1'] = np.select([df['Race 1'] == 700, df['Race 1'].between(200, 300, inclusive='left')], ['White', 'Asian'], np.nan)
```

Comment: So when I run your code I get the same error message: TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'. Do I need to change the type to int? And how do I do that if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: Have you read the full answer? As soon as you assign back to the original `Race 1' column, it ceases to be numeric and becomes objet. Then any further comparison will trigger an error. Try the alternatives suggested in the end of the answer (on a clean DataFrame!)

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry I didn't catch that.